# Multiply elements of array in bash

Tags: bash, bc

I have two arrays

```
value={00..23}
i=(01 02)
```

When I multiply them using the following command, I get results but I need another format ... I need the result as

```
00, 01...18, ...36
```

and now I get,

```
0,1 ..8, 18,..36

t=$(expr $value*$i | bc)
```

Anybody can show me the way?

and if I want to sum up 24 at value when I get the second element of the array days and zero if I get the first element of the array days at value...I have used the following code without success...

```
#!/bin/bash

data=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
data1=`date -d "1 day" +%Y-%m-%d`

days=("$data" "$data1")
for day in "${days[@]}"; do
for value in {00..23}; do
# here I order to sum up 00 if I get the first day, and if I get the second day, I order to sum up 24 at value...
if [[ "$day"="${days[0]}" ]]; then i=00
else
i=24
fi
t=$((10#$i+10#$value))
echo $t
done
done
```

I should get 00, 01, 02...23, 24, 25, 26...48..but i don't get it....

Comment: You have one array; `value` is just a space-separated string.

Comment: even worse, `value` is just the (verbatim) string `{00..23}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear. I guess you're in this situation:

```
value=( {00..23} ) # <--- this defines an array, unlike your code in the question
i=( 01 02 )
```

and you want to loop through the arrays `value` and `i` and multiply the terms. You don't need `expr` and `bc` for this, since you're only dealing with integers. The only catch is that is that you have a leading `0`; so we have to take extra care to tell Bash we really mean numbers in radix 10 (and not in radix 8), using the radix specifier `10#`. Also, we deal with your formatting problem using `printf`:

```
for a in "${i[@]}"; do
    for b in "${value[@]}"; do
        printf '%02d\n' "$((10#$a*10#$b))"
    done
done
```

This will print to *standard out* the following:

```
00
01
02
03
04
[...]
22
23
00
02
04
06
[...]
44
46
```

If you want to make a new array out of these, proceed as follows:

```
newarray=()
for a in "${i[@]}"; do
    for b in "${value[@]}"; do
        printf -v fab '%02d' "$((10#$a*10#$b))"
        newarray+=( "$fab" )
    done
done
```

Then,

```
declare -p newarray
```

will show:

```
declare -a newarray='([0]="00" [1]="01" [2]="02" [3]="03" [4]="04" [5]="05" [6]="06" [7]="07" [8]="08" [9]="09" [10]="10" [11]="11" [12]="12" [13]="13" [14]="14" [15]="15" [16]="16" [17]="17" [18]="18" [19]="19" [20]="20" [21]="21" [22]="22" [23]="23" [24]="00" [25]="02" [26]="04" [27]="06" [28]="08" [29]="10" [30]="12" [31]="14" [32]="16" [33]="18" [34]="20" [35]="22" [36]="24" [37]="26" [38]="28" [39]="30" [40]="32" [41]="34" [42]="36" [43]="38" [44]="40" [45]="42" [46]="44" [47]="46")'
```

---

Regarding your edit: the line

```
if [[ "$day"="${days[0]}" ]]; then i=00
```

is wrong: you need spaces around the `=` sign (otherwise Bash only tests whether the string obtained by the expansion `"$day"="${days[0]}"` is not empty… and this string is never empty!—that's because Bash only sees *one* argument between the `[[...]]`). Write this instead:

```
if [[ "$day" = "${days[0]}" ]]; then i=00
```

Now, actually, your script would be clearer (and shorter and more efficient) without the hard-coded `24`, and without this test for each iteration of the loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

data=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
data1=$(date -d "1 day" +%Y-%m-%d)

days=( "$data" "$data1" )
values=( {00..23} )

for day in "${days[@]}"; do
   for value in "${values[@]}"; do
      t=$((10#$i+10#$value))
      echo "$t"
   done
   ((i+=${#values[@]}))
done
```

Comment: thanks for the comments. @gniourf_gniourf I have another doubt, I explain it on my question above

Comment: @EnricAgudPique: post edited to answer your question…